# Facebook Pagetab App - user likes

Tags: php, facebook, sdk, facebook-apps

I'm using the Facebook SDK and we created an app which worked just as we needed. We could `$FacebookSDK->getSignedRequest()` in PHP and it would respond with an object that included `pages->liked` which allowed us to determine if the user likes the page or not.

Anyway, we have created an exact duplicate application (the only difference being that this app is about 3 months newer than the old) and the `like` property has completely disappeared and I can't get my hands on it.

Any ideas why this is happening - has Facebook restricted their SDK yet further and removed this property for new apps?

**Example Before:**

```
stdClass Object
(
    [algorithm] => HMAC-SHA256
    [issued_at] => 1408626697
    [page] => stdClass Object
        (
            [id] => ************
            [admin] => 1
            [liked] => 1
        )

    [user] => stdClass Object
        (
            [country] => gb
            [locale] => en_GB
            [age] => stdClass Object
                (
                    [min] => 21
                )
        )
)
```

**Example After:**

```
stdClass Object
(
    [algorithm] => HMAC-SHA256
    [issued_at] => 1408625335
    [page] => stdClass Object
        (
            [id] => ************
            [admin] => 1
        )

    [user] => stdClass Object
        (
            [country] => gb
            [locale] => en_GB
            [age] => stdClass Object
                (
                    [min] => 21
                )
        )
)
```

Notice that the only thing missing here is the likes property so I can't tell if the user likes our page tab or not! Facebook is doing my nut in to develop on these days!

Thanks,
Chris.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

https://developers.facebook.com/docs/apps/changelog

(see v2.1 changes)

Fan-/Like-Gates are not possible anymore, and not allowed according to the Platform Policy. Old Apps will always return "true" in the signed_request parameter after 5th of November 2014.

Comment: Oh great well nice of Facebook to help developers thrive with great apps! Thanks for the answer :) Shame they are doing this though, I would be interested to see what other people think?

Comment: as a facebook developer, i am actually VERY happy that they finally got rid of fangates. they were always annoying and we told our customers since many years that they are bad :)

Comment: that's true and I guess in many ways its a benefit - it's just all our customers know! Time to come up with some new ideas :)