# isLiked() returns nothing in phpsdk4 for Facebook

Tags: php, facebook, helper, facebook-sdk-4.0

I have this problem. I was created **facebook tab app** application in developer fb, app I'm turn on.

I use this code. Unfortunately  it doesn't work function isLiked(). Where is problem?

```
<?php
require 'phpsdk4/autoload.php';

use Facebook\FacebookSession;
use Facebook\FacebookPageTabHelper;

FacebookSession::setDefaultApplication('XXX', 'YYY');

$helper = new FacebookPageTabHelper();

echo '<p>page id: ' . $helper->getPageId() . '</p>';
echo '<p>liked: ' . $helper->isLiked() . '</p>';  
echo '<p>admin: ' . $helper->isAdmin() . '</p>';
?>
```

Function pageid and admin work correct. Unfortunately  function isLiked() return nothing. 
Where is problem?

Thank you

Edit: I am try refresh page, if page like or not, however function return nothing.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Facebook Pagetab App - user likes](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25427414/facebook-pagetab-app-user-likes)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If your application was created after August 7th 2014, the isLiked() parameter will no longer work as Facebook are disabling this functionality. The ability to see if a user likes a page will be completely removed on November 5th 2014.

From November 5th 2014, all apps will see `liked` = `true`, even if the user hasn't liked the page. Facebook is basically removing the ability to Likegate apps.

[You can read more about this policy change here](https://www.webniraj.com/2014/08/12/facebook-api-graph-api-v2-1-now-available-likegates-no-longer-allowed/).